# Linq parameter error

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query

```
public IEnumerable<TimesheetModel> FilterByUserId(IEnumerable<TimesheetModel> obj, int FilterUserId)
{
     var query = (from list in obj.Where(x => x.List.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(FilterUserId)))
                  select new TimesheetModel
                  {
                      TaskDate = list.TaskDate,
                      List = list.List
                  }).ToList();

     return query;
}
```

And I have error:

> A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it
>   would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a
>   'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Why I have this error and how to solve this?

I have this model

```
public class TimesheetModel
{
    public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TimesheetListModel> List { get; set; }

    public TimesheetModel() { List = new List<TimesheetListModel>(); }
}
```

And

```
public class TimesheetListModel
    {
        public DateTime Date        { get; set; }
        public bool?    InProgress  { get; set; }
        public string   Note        { get; set; }
        public int      ProjectId   { get; set; }
        public string   ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string   Task        { get; set; }
        public decimal? TimeWorked  { get; set; }
        public int?     Type        { get; set; }
        public int      UserId      { get; set; }
        public string   UserName    { get; set; }
        public int?     WorkItemId  { get; set; }

    }
```

And my task is filtering by UserId this model

```
{
    "TaskDate": "2015-01-04T00:00:00",
    "List": [
        {
            "WorkItemId":24,
            "ProjectId":3,
            "ProjectName":"Hello world",
            "UserId":12,
            "UserName":"Anatoliy Svetliakov",
            "Date":"2015-01-04T22:00:00",
            "Task":"#34 : New task test",
            "TimeWorked":2,
            "Note":null,
            "InProgress":false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with desired output.

Comment: Because you do two times `x => x` in your `from`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you were using x as variable inside two lambda expressions(obj.Where, that is parent scope & list.Where, which is current scope),try this:

```
   public IEnumerable<TimesheetModel> FilterByUserId(IEnumerable<TimesheetModel> obj, int FilterUserId)
    {
         var query = (from list in obj.Where(z=>z.List.Any(u=>u.UserId==FilterUserId))
                      select new TimesheetModel
                      {
                          TaskDate = list.TaskDate,
                          List = list.List.Where(o=> o.UserId.Equals(FilterUserId)).FirstOrDefault()
                      }).ToList();

         return query;
    }
```

Comment: But I have error when I write like this:
`Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<Helpdesk.Infrastructure.WorkLog.TimesheetModel,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type`
 and 
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Helpdesk.Infrastructure.WorkLog.TimesheetListModel>' to 'bool'`

Comment: this is because your linq query is wrong. please mention what you want to achieve & I will correct it. The list.Where returns a list & not a boolean, it should return a boolean.

Comment: @HUSTLIN You should add this to your question instead of to this answer.

Comment: @Nikita I added task to question

Comment: the updated answer takes the models which has values in List for the filterUserId & returns the taskDate & matching record from List.

Answer (score 2):

Error message is self explanatory, you need different variable there:-

```
from list in obj.Where(x => x.List.Where(z => z.UserId.Equals(FilterUserId)))
```

Also, you query should be using `Any` instead of `Where` when comparing `UserId`:-

```
 var query = (from list in obj.Where(x => x.List.Any(z => z.UserId.Equals(FilterUserId)))
                  select new TimesheetModel
                  {
                      TaskDate = list.TaskDate,
                      List = list.List
                  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a diferent variable than x as below:

```
 var query = (from list in obj.Where(x => x.List.Where(y => y.UserId.Equals(FilterUserId)))
                  select new TimesheetModel
                  {
                      TaskDate = list.TaskDate,
                      List = list.List
                  }).ToList();
```